# Percentage-wise, how much difference in performance is there, on average, between these 2 methods?

Tags: c++, optimization, hardware

I have a question as I try to understand the implementation of the standard library.

Given

```
std::vector<int> myVec = { ... }; // some vector of ints
```

which of the following is faster on average, and by how much, and why?

(1)

```
for (int i(0), j(myVec.size()); i < j; ++i) std::cout << myVec[i];
```

or

(2)

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator i(myVec.begin()), j(myVec.end()); i != j; ++i) std::cout << *it;
```

Comment: Why don't you measure them?

Comment: [Performance Rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I'm interested in the theory behind their differing implementations. I want to know what happens differently at the hardware level.

Comment: Given that both are writing to `std::cout`, there's basically no chance at all of being able to measure any difference at all. But what you probably want to use is  `for (auto i : myVec) cout << i;`.

Comment: Are you using optimizations?  What does the assembly language look like for both cases using high levels of optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's see...

The first loop:  Calling `size` member function, N times `operator[]` on `std::vector` object and N times `operator<<` on `std::cout`.

The second loop:  Calling `begin` and `end` member functions on `std::vector` object, N times dereferencing a `vector<int>::iterator` and N times `operator<<` on `std::cout`.

The following operations: `size`, `operator[]`, `begin`, `end` and dereferencing `vector<int>::iterator` have constant complexity.  In other words, nothing much.  `operator[]` will probably result in adding some number to a base address and vector iterator is most likely a raw pointer.  It's clear that printing stuff on standard output is what dominates here that is the same in both cases.  There's no reason to believe that one of them is going to be faster than the other in general.

Just for fun I tried that on my laptop and I don't see any difference worth talking about.

Gdb disassembly: gcc 4.8 (g++ -g -std=c++11 -O2 file.cc):

```
    Dump of assembler code for function main():
    5       {
       0x0000000000400880 <+0>:     push   %r12
       0x000000000040088d <+13>:    push   %rbp
       0x000000000040088e <+14>:    push   %rbx

    6         std::vector<int> myVec = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 }; // some vector of ints
    7
    8         for (int i(0), j(myVec.size()); i < j; ++i) std::cout << myVec[i];
       0x0000000000400887 <+7>:     mov    $0x6,%r12d
       0x000000000040088f <+15>:    xor    %ebx,%ebx
       0x00000000004008c0 <+64>:    mov    0x0(%rbp,%rbx,4),%esi
       0x00000000004008c4 <+68>:    mov    $0x601080,%edi
       0x00000000004008c9 <+73>:    callq  0x4007d0 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
       0x00000000004008ce <+78>:    add    $0x1,%rbx
       0x00000000004008d2 <+82>:    cmp    %ebx,%r12d
       0x00000000004008d5 <+85>:    jg     0x4008c0 <main()+64>

    9
    10        std::cout << std::endl;
    11
    12        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it(myVec.begin()), j(myVec.end()); it != j; ++it) std::cout << *it;
       0x00000000004008f0 <+112>:   mov    (%rbx),%esi
       0x00000000004008f2 <+114>:   mov    $0x601080,%edi
       0x00000000004008f7 <+119>:   callq  0x4007d0 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
       0x00000000004008fc <+124>:   add    $0x4,%rbx
       0x0000000000400900 <+128>:   cmp    %r12,%rbx
       0x0000000000400903 <+131>:   jne    0x4008f0 <main()+112>

    13
    14        std::cout << std::endl;
    15      }
       0x000000000040091c <+156>:   pop    %rbx
       0x000000000040091d <+157>:   pop    %rbp
       0x000000000040091e <+158>:   xor    %eax,%eax
       0x0000000000400920 <+160>:   pop    %r12
       0x0000000000400922 <+162>:   retq
```

Answer (score 0):

Second case is faster.

When you Increment iterator you just increment pointer.

Access to element with index include multiplication of index on size of type, in order to calculate pointer.

Comment: Sorry, but not completely correct.  Some processors have the instructions for indexing from a pointer value or a register.  Also depends on the size of the data item.

Answer (score 0):

Too many dependencies and unknowns involved in this question.

In the first case, you are calling a function to access an element.  The function may be optimized to remove the overhead of the function call and boils down to a multiplication and addition operation.

The second case involves dereferencing of a pointer to access memory.

One of the issues here is the processor's capabilities.  Many modern processors have the ability to fetch values from memory, either by derefencing (using an index of zero) or by indexing from a pointer, using a single instruction.

Another affect is whether the vector can fit in the processor's cache line (if it has a data cache).  Any data outside the cache line will require extra processing logic.

If one method is faster than the other, it is negligible unless you are performing 1E+10 iterations.  The difference is usually in units of nano seconds.  Your program will waste more time being swapped out by the OS, calling a function or performing I/O.  An example:  the difference is 10ns.  your program waits 0.5 seconds for the User to input a value.  The gain of 10ns per iteration is wasted waiting for the User input.

Usually, these kind of micro-optimizations are only critical for high performance applications or applications that must meet critical deadlines.  For example, if an embedded system has to read from a sensor every millisecond, then the less time spent reading the sensor is more time that the rest of the system gets to execute.

**Edit 1:**
A micro-optimization like this one also depends on where the data is coming from.  The further away from the processor's core that the memory is, the slower the fetch.  For example, fetching from memory on the same piece of silicon would be faster than accessing from a Flash device located on a daughter board.